# Entity framework 6 generate file per entity

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am a beginner of Entity framework and i am trying to migrate ( as per the migration guidelines ) one of the project from entity framework 4 to entity framework 6. At present, all entities in that project are present in separate cs file and the same way i wanna keep it after migrate to EF6. I have seen some example how to keep entities in seperate files in EF4 ( model.tt template file ) but i could not find any example how to do it EF6 ( model.tt template file )

The model.tt file is similar to this link

https://github.com/vc3/ExoModel/blob/master/ExoModel.EntityFramework/DataModel.tt

Please help to how keep entities in separate file in EF6

Comment: Use the EF Reverse POCO template, and configure it to generate seperate files

Comment: After struggle i have figured out that existing project uses EF4 ste generator and STE is not available in EF6. I feel i have to stick with EF4.